# Customize the way TreeSet prints Map.Entry values

Tags: java, string-formatting, treeset

I have a `TreeSet` containing `Map.Entry<String, Double>` values and when I try to use an `Iterator` to iterate over this structure and to print its key-value pairs, the standard output is something which looks like:

```
Tolkien=40.25 JKRowling=35.5 OBowden=14.0
```

However I would like to use a **custom format** for my output and to replace the `=` sign with `->` like:

```
Tolkien -> 40.25, JKRowling -> 35.5, OBowden -> 14.0
```

This is my code for now:

```
Iterator iterator;.
iterator = lib.getSortedBooks().iterator(); 
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.printf(iterator.next() + " ");
}
```

Which is the best way to **properly format my output**?

Comment: *I have a TreeSet containing Map.Entry values* - Why wouldn't you use a TreeMap?

Comment: Because it automatically sorts its elements. I could think of `lib` building a sorted sequence of books with `lib.getSortedBooks()` and therefore returning a `TreeSet`. However there may be more appropriate data structures for iterating data sorted.

Comment: @Zabuza `TreeSet` also automatically sorts its elements. I'm not seeing the distinction.

Comment: If you don't want sorting, then TreeSet is not the right choice. How about LinkedHashSet (items are unique according to eq / hc, but insertion order is preserved)?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you are asking why it uses a **Tree-like** structure in the first place. Indeed, a `TreeMap<String, Double>` would have a similar result than a `TreeSet<Entry<String, Double>>` and is more readable. However I think the best approach would be to use a `Book` class instead of `Map.Entry<String, Double>` which is very non-flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing methods in `System.out` use `toString()` internally, so when you call `toString()` you get the same thing that you see in the output. Then just replace that equals sign with the arrow.

```
System.out.printf(iterator.next().toString().replace("=", " -> ") + " ");
```

A more elegant approach (actually the right way to do it since `Map.Entry` makes no promise as to the `toString()` format):

```
Map.Entry<K, V> entry = iterator.next();
System.out.printf(entry.getKey() + " -> " + entry.getValue() + " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could fix your issue by simply replacing the `=` character with `->` characters like:

```
Iterator<Entry<String, Double>> iterator = lib.getSortedBooks().iterator(); 
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Entry book = iterator.next();
    String bookAsText = book.toString();
    String adjustedText = bookAsText.replace("=", " -> ");

    System.out.print(adjustedText + ", ");
}
```

Note that your output now has a trailing `,` in the end. You can either remove that with the `String#substring` method or don't append it if you're processing the last element (look one element ahead with `iterator.hasNext()`) or just use `StringJoiner` which I'll show you in a moment.

---

However if you always want **that explicit output** then you should **not rely** on the `toString` method printing it the way it does. This may change in future, who knows.

You should explicitly build the output. Helpful for this is the [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class which lets you join strings with adding a delimiter like `,`. Therefore use a code like this:

```
Set<Entry<String, Double>> books = lib.getSortedBooks();
String entryDelimiter = ", "
String valueDelimiter = " -> ";

StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(entryDelimiter);
for (Entry<String, Double> book : books) {
    sj.add(book.getKey());
    sj.add(valueDelimiter);
    sj.add(book.getValue());
}
String output = sj.toString();

System.out.println(output);
```

---

Or a more compact **Java 8** solution using `Streams`:

```
String output = lib.getSortedBooks().stream()
    .map(book -> book.getKey() + " -> " + book.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

System.out.println(output);
```

The approach uses the set as source for an stream. Then it first transfers every element into `book.getKey() + "->" + book.getValue()`, this is what `Stream#map` does. After that it joins all those elements with `,` and finally collects them.

Note that it can also be parallelized if its okay for you that elements are not sorted anymore. Therefore just call the `Stream#parallel` in between. It may "*convert*" the given stream to a parallel one.

---

Depending on the size of your project you should think about changing the representation of your books from `Map.Entry` to an own class `Book` like:

```
public class Book() {
    private final String mAuthor;
    private final double mPrice;

    public Book(final String author, final double price) {
        this.mAuthor = author;
        this.mPrice = price;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return this.mAuthor;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.mPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getAuthor + " -> " + getPrice();
    }
}
```

This approach is far more flexible for future changes and also allows you to add a `toString` representation that you find the most appropriate.

Because then, assuming `lib.getSortedBooks()` returns a set of `Book` instead of `Map.Entry`, you can simply do:

```
String output = lib.getSortedBooks().stream()
    .map(Book::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: *However if you always want that explicit output then you should not rely on the toString method printing it the way it does. This may change in future, who knows.* That depends on the particular implementation. Many have explicit `toString()` specifications.

Comment: Well yes, but also many implementations of `Map`, `Set` and `Entry`

Comment: Yep. It will work as long as OP sticks to `Map.Entry` but as soon as changing the underlying model, for example by adding more attributes to books, then an explicit build of the output will be necessary at some point.